# C++ implicit data conversion with struct

Tags: c++, struct, casting, implicit-conversion

With C++ I can do implicit data conversions so in below example to reduce the explicit use of `reinterpret_cast`. How do I handle the case here marked with `TODO`, so from `char*` to `DATA_IMP*`

```
struct DATA_EXP
{
    int f1;
    int f2;
};


struct DATA_IMP
{
    int f1;
    int f2;

    operator char*() { return reinterpret_cast<char*>(this); }
};

char* doSomething(char * data)
{
    data[0] = 2;
    return data;
}

int main()
{
    DATA_EXP d1e;
    char* d1er = doSomething(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d1e));
    DATA_EXP* d2e = reinterpret_cast<DATA_EXP*>(d1er);

    DATA_IMP d1i;
    char* d1ir = doSomething(d1i);
    DATA_IMP* d2i = d1ir; // TODO how to handle?

    return d2e->f1 + d1e.f1 + d1i.f1 + d2i->f1;
}
```

Comment: Plain bad code (too much hacking)

Comment: Please pay attention to only the line with the comment. Everything else is just plain bad context explanation.

Comment: Linked duplicate question does not provide any sample codes for the wrapping solution.

Comment: @ckain Either write that yourself, or, if you can make an on-topic question out of the issue, ask a new and specific question for that. In general, SO is not a code writing service; so *"answer does not spoon feed copy-pastable code"* is not a valid reason to complain.